# help setting up web root to point to /web

Tags: craft3, config, install

I'm new to Craft 3 and I need help getting the web root to point to /web.

I can't figure it out. If I use the url "mysite.com/web" everything works fine.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: This is more about your web server than about Craft itself. In order to help we need to know what server you use. Can you set up a vHost or do you have access to the configuration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a web server configuration question, not a Craft question.

Comment: Voting to leave open because it's a Craft-relevant answer, and could be helpful to other Craft users. It has also (now) drawn a correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure your webserver/virtualhost to point to the /web directory.

For apache you have `DocumentRoot: your_disk_path/web`

For nginx you have `root: your_disk_path/web`